# Behaviour of passing struct as a parameter to a CUDA kernel

Tags: class, oop, struct, cuda, parameter-passing

I'm relatively new to CUDA programming, so I want to clarify the behaviour of a struct when I pass it into a kernel.  I've defined the following `struct` to somewhat imitate the behavior of a 3D array that knows its own size:

```
struct protoarray {
    size_t dim1;
    size_t dim2;
    size_t dim3;
    float* data;
};
```

I create two variables of type `protoarray`, dynamically allocate space to data via malloc and cudaMalloc on the host and device side, and update `dim1`, `dim2` and `dim3` to reflect the size of array I want this struct to represent.  I read in [this thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/passing-structs-to-kernel/13085) that the `struct` should be passed via copy.  So this is what I do in my kernel

```
__global__ void kernel(curandState_t *state, protoarray arr_device){
    const size_t dim1 = arr_device.dim1;
    const size_t dim2 = arr_device.dim2;
    
    for(size_t j(0); j < dim2; j++){
        for(size_t i(0); i < dim1; i++){
            // Do something 
        }
    }
}
```

The struct is passed by copy, so all its contents are copied into shared memory of each block.  This is where I'm getting bizarre behaviour, which I'm hoping you could help me with.  Suppose I had set `arr_device.dim1 = 2` on the host side.  While debugging inside the kernel and setting a breakpoint at one of the `for` loops, checking the value of `arr_device.dim1` yields something like `16776576`, nowhere large enough to cause overflow, but this value copies correctly into `dim1` as `2`, which means that the `for` loops execute as I intended them to.  As a side question, is using `size_t` which is essential `unsigned long long int` bad practice, seeing as the GPU's are made of 32bit cores?

Generally, how safe is it to pass `struct` and `class` into kernels as arguments, is bad practice that should be avoided at all cost?  I imagine that passing pointers to classes to kernels is difficult in case they contain members which point to dynamically allocated memory, and that they should be very lightweight if I want to pass them by value.

Comment: Are you sure `size_t` is the same size on both the CPU and GPU? (And `struct`s without constructors are generally safe, I believe.)

Comment: @KenY-N: CUDA guarantees that `sizof(size_t)` and `sizeof(void *)` are the same on the GPU and device *for whatever platform is being used*. It might not be the same from platform to platform

Comment: This worries me -- "The struct is passed by copy, so all its contents are copied into shared memory of each block". That isn't at all how things work. And whatever the problem is, it isn't being caused by anything you have shown in this question. [MCVE], please

Comment: @KenY-N Changed all to `unsigned int`, and now the values match.  Could you please refer me to some source which refers to the issue of `struct`'s with constructors in kernels?
@talonmies ""The struct is passed by copy, so all its contents are copied into shared memory of each block" this is essentially a citation from the NVIDIA developer forum thread I linked.

Comment: @SlavaK.: OK, that was true in 2009. It hasn't been true since 2010. All kernel arguments go in a dedicated constant memory bank on all CUDA hardware except the very first generation G80/G90 parts

Comment: @talomnies Your were right, the incorrect values were due to bad code outside the kernel.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a partial answer, since without a [proper program to look into](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it is difficult/impossible to guess why you would see an invalid value in your `arr_device.dim1`.

> The struct is passed by copy, so all its contents are copied into shared memory of each block.

**Incorrect**. Kernel arguments are stored in constant memory, which is device-global and not block-specific. They are not stored shared memory (which is block-specific).

When a thread runs, it typically reads arguments from constant memory into registers (and again, not shared memory).

> Generally, how safe is it to pass struct and class into kernels as arguments

My personal rule of thumb on this matter is: If the struct/class...

- is trivially-copy-constructible; and
- all its members of the struct/class are defined both for the host and the device side, or at least - designed with GPU use in mind;

then it should be safe to pass to a kernel.

<sub>(Now it's a bit more of a rule of thumb, and I actually enforce the first part of this rule in the [Modern C++ wrappers for CUDA](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers), in the [innermost code for launching kernels](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/blob/ae1747e1d32d287c0b40074d789a4cf435fdb36e/src/cuda/api/multi_wrapper_impls/kernel_launch.hpp#L25).)</sub>

> passing struct and class into kernels as arguments [ - ] is [it] bad practice that should be avoided at all cost?

**No**. But remember that most C++ libraries only provide host-side code; and were not written with a mind of being used on a GPU. So I'd be wary of using non-trivial classes without a lot of scrutiny.

> I imagine that passing pointers to classes to kernels is difficult in case they contain members which point to dynamically allocated memory

**Yes, this can be problematic**. However - if you used `cuda::memory::managed::allocate()`, `cuda::memory::managed::make_unique()` or `cudaMallocManaged()` - then this should "just work", i.e. the relevant memory pages will be fetched to the GPU or the CPU as necessary when accessed. See:

- [Unified Memory in CUDA for beginners](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/)
- [Beyond GPU Memory Limits with Unified Memory on Pascal](http://Beyond%20GPU%20Memory%20Limits%20with%20Unified%20Memory%20on%20Pascal)

> and that they should be very lightweight if I want to pass [objects to kernels] by value.

**Yes**,  because *each and every thread* has to read each argument from constant memory before it can use that argument. And while constant memory allows this to happen relatively quickly, it's still a bunch of overhead that you want to minimize.

Also remember that you can't pass anything to kernels by (C++) reference; it's all "by-value" - the object itself or a pointer to it.

Comment: Historical side note: Very early CUDA (before it became public) allowed only one kernel argument. So I wrote a lot of kernels using a `struct` as a collection of all kernel arguments. A significant portion of that code survived for many years and without any problems on any system that I recall.

Comment: @konovification: If this answers your question, please mark it as Accepted (press the V mark). And if you like it (regardless of acceptance) - upvote it; that's all the thanks necessary.